# background-color elementos

Tags: css, css3

Hola a todos estoy trabajando una plantilla con css puro, sin tocar el html ni añadiéndole clases, lo que necesito es ponerle un fondo a los elementos p y h2 pero me genera un espaciado, se lo quito agregando un margin y un padding 0 pero este me pega el contenido con el header y no se como solucionarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
h2 {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
    display: flex;
    width: 60%;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    color: #db344b;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px 10px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
    margin-top: 80px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #acdadc;

}
```

```
p {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: #acdadc;
}
```

Comment: El color de fondo no afecta al posicionamiento. Coloca el código HTML para intentar ver el problema.

Comment: @Juan el  html es texto dentro de  h2 y elementos p no se pueden añadir clases

Comment: Lo del ver el HTML es solo para terminar de entender el problema. Las etiquetas h2 y p son bloques que agregan espacio al interlineado por defecto.

Comment: @Juan Literalmente es la estructura basica de html con el texto dentro de h2 y p es decir algo como esto: <p>texto de relleno</p> y <h2> encabezado</h2> todo esto va dentro del body no tiene divs ni nada solo son etiquetas p y h2